# Split a string array into another array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to split a large text file into single words as I need to shuffle the letters of each word.

```
ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
```

This is show I read in the textfile with text and gives an output of:

```
[This is Line One. , This is Line Two. , This is Line three. , End.]
```

How do I split this into {This, is, Line, One} etc?
I tried

```
aryLines.split("\\s+");
```

but it doesnt work as aryLines is a array...

Comment: You have to do this for each line with e.g. a for loop

Comment: Try this: `aryLines.split(" ");` this should force the lines to split into single words. If you want to incorporate punctuation, then you are going to have to manipulate your `split()` to incorporate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (String string : arrLines) {
            string.split(",");
    }
```

you have and array, you just need to do a for each and split the content in each array you get.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Given :

```
String[] aryLines = {
    "This is Line One.", "This is Line Two.", "This is Line three.", "End."
};
```

To obtain the result you're seeking, you need to split the content of the array, not the array itself :

```
ArrayList<List<String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (String aString : aryLines) {
    arrayList.add(Arrays.asList(aString.split("\\s+")));
}
```

If you print `arrayList` it you'll get :

```
[[This, is, Line, One.], [This, is, Line, Two.], [This, is, Line, three.], [End.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large the file is you could either read the file into a String then call split with a regex like

```
 string.split("(\\ )");
```

This would give you a String array with the words (and punctuation).

Or if the file is very large you can read it line by line like you currently are and then split each line by iterating over it and adding the split words into a collection.

```
ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String line : aryLines) {
    for (String word : line.split("\\ ")) {
        words.add(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: 
Here, I am just getting the output for the first part, i.e, "This is Line One." splitted and stored in array "aryLines1" as {This, is, Line, One.}

```
public class TestingArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


        File file  = new File("D:\\1-PROJECTS\\test.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
            list.add(s);
        }

        String[] aryLines = list.toArray(new String[0]);    
        String[] aryLines1 = aryLines[0].split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<aryLines1.length;i++){
            System.out.println(aryLines1[i].toString());
        }

    }

}
```

The **Output** comes out to be:-
**This

is

Line

One.**

This is the content stored in array **"aryLines1"**.

Similarly you can split **"aryLines"** using **(" ")** and store in other arrays as well.